# Hashmaps with boolean function

Tags: hashmap, maps

I'm trying to understand hashmaps and I thought of an extension to hashmaps in which two separate hashmaps X and Y are used, and a Boolean function, B(n), is provided.

For every key, n, B(n) is computed, and if B(n)=true then X is used, otherwise Y is used.

How would this work? And what would be the good/bad side of using this method to select hashmaps?

Comment: @jsotola Hashmap A is used if the boolean returns true.

Comment: @jsotola I've just edited my question, so X and Y are two different hashmaps. While B(n) is a boolean function. Based on B(n) result for every key, a hashmap is selected.

Comment: Could you clarify "how would this work?"

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to create a data structure that looks like the following:

```
class EitherMap<K, V> { 
    // cannot implement Map interface because some methods don't have a Key parameter
    private final Map<K, V> map1, map2;
    private final Predicate<K> map1Predicate;

    EitherMap(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2, Predicate<K> map1Predicate) {
       this.map1 = map1;
       this.map2 = map2;
       this.map1Predicate = map1Predicate;
    }

    boolean containsKey(K k) {
       return map1Predicate.test(k) ? map1.containsKey(k) : map2.containsKey(k);
    }

    V get(K k) {
       // ...
    }

    V put(K k, V v) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

I doubt you can find a use case for this data structure tho